# Hide Cividiscount box from specific contribution page

Tags: civicontribute, cividiscount

When you apply a discount to a membership type any contribution page with this membership type shows the discount box. Is there a way to hide the box on particular contribution pages or make discounts admin only I.e only admins can apply a discount? This ways not all members are shown this option and only specific ones can tagged with a discount.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few options to make it so only Admins can apply discounts.

1. Create a price set for memberships and add a text/numeric quantity field called 'Discount', set the value to $-1.00 and set the visibility to 'Admin'. With this option you can apply custom discounts when entering memberships via the admin panel without using a CiviDiscount Code. The special field for discounts will only be visible to logged in admins.
2. If you are comfortable with some coding you can use jQuery to hide the CiviDiscount form section from the contribution page template via a custom template. Keep in mind this will hide the CiviDiscount form from all contribution pages.

Hope this helps

Comment: Or in your extra.registration template conditionally hide the civiDiscount form

Comment: Thanks guys. Option 1 of KilakwaBT's answer worked well. I can manually apply the price sets to members with different discount options. I have not tried % as an option but fixed price works well. Cheers.

Comment: Does it seem like a worthwhile addition to have a new feature added so the discount can ONLY be applied by admin?